# why select 5 from emp does not give error

Tags: oracle, select

If emp table contains 14 rows and when I execute `SELECT 5 FROM EMP` why does it show following output instead of showing error

```
5
-----
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

Why It just makes 5 as column alias and provides results repeated rows as numeric 5 up to number of rows of table.

On the other hand, it doesn't work

```
SQL> select something from emp;
select something from emp
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SOMETHING": invalid identifier
```

Comment: seems like valid sql to me, what is your problem with it?

Comment: yes, but my doubt is, there is no any column `5` exist in emp table. Then, why it get executed and showing this output. What is the logic behind it. ?

Comment: you are not selecting a column, you are selecting a value. i think in oracle if you write `SELECT "5" FROM emp` , the qoutes force the engine to interpret 5 as a column name, then it would be an error

Comment: You can put several things in that spot. These are, among others, strings (`"something"`), column names (`something`) that give an error if they don't exist, number (`5`), etc. The logic is that things (bunch of letters, a number) are treated differently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error because you are selecting a static value of `5` and this is repeated for each row in the table.  This is the same thing as using:

```
select id, 5
from emp
```

You will return all ids but you will also return the column with the value of `5` for all rows.  It is valid SQL so there would be no error.

This is just selecting a constant value as a column, you receive no error because it is a number, if you wanted to do the same thing with a string, you will wrap the value in single quotes:

```
select id, 'something'
from emp
```

Since you are selecting from a table, you will return the constant value for each row in the table.

If you changed the query to select from dual, you would return only one row, but your table has 14 rows so the value repeats for each row.

Comment: I know, but my question is why ?

Comment: `5` works because it is a number, your second version `something` will work if you place single quotes around it.  This works because it is a static value.

Comment: Can you please explain, what happens behind the scene. I will be thankful.

Comment: @jWeavers Your table has 14 rows, since you are selecting from the table the constant value is repeated for each row.

Answer (score 2):

You [`select`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2080424) one or more expressions, which may be [simple expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions002.htm).

The syntax diagram for a simple expression shows that a number, or another fixed value, is valid - so all you are doing is selecting a constant value, `5`, for each of the rows in your table.

Pointless perhaps, but perfectly valid. (I usually select `8`, by typing too quickly and mistyping `*`...). It's being aliased to `"5"` by default because it has to be called something; otherwise this would fail:

```
 select "5" from (select 5 from dual);
```

In your second example, there is no column called `something`, but if you want to get a constant string then it will work:

```
 select 'something' from dual;
```

Without quotes, `something` would be a valid name for a column so Oracle tries to interpret it as that and fails, because there is no such column. `5` is not a valid column name (see [the object naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm) so there is no confusion and it's interpreted as a fixed value, not a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You select 14 rows (the number of rows in th `emp` table). The *value* you select is constantly `5`, for each row. So, you get 14 rows, each containing `5`.

The column is also named as `5` implicitly, based on your query.

---

```
select something from emp;
```

`something` is neither a constant, nor a column. Not even an expression. If you would say

```
select 'something' from emp;
```

then you would get 14 rows, each containing a text (varchar) value of `something`.